# SSMS 17 Database Diagram Table View Type Update not working

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms-17

In SQL Server Management Studio 2017, while creating a new database diagram or updating the existing one, the default Table View type is Column Names.

But when I try to change the table view type, it gets changed to STANDARD irrespective of what table view type I have selected. Then if I try to change it back to Column Names, nothing happens. It remains stuck at STANDARD table view type.

I have tried repairing my SSMS and VS installations but nothing worked so far.

Any advice please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: I had to reopen it in SSMS2012 or up, edit it there, and then afterwards reopen it in SSMS-17

Answer (score 3):

We are having the exact same problem with SSMS v17.1 (14.0.17119.0)
The only solution we have found is to remove the table from the diagram and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

While this issue is still existing, you can change the "Default table view" in

Tools > Option > Designers > Table and Database Designers

Then when you add new tables they will be the desired layout, without changing the ones previously added.